# Expo Application Services not applying correct env variable to app.config

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, eas

I'm building an app through EAS and I have two env files, `.env.development` and `.end.production`, and also 2 build profiles at the moment:

```
"build": {
    "development": {
      "channel": "development",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "ENVFILE": ".env.development"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "ENVFILE": ".env.production"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
```

in the dev env files i have some variables:

```
ENV_NAME=development
APP_NAME=MyApp DEV
API_URL=https://api-dev-v2.app.com/
APP_SCHEME=myapp-dev
BUNDLE_ID=com.myapp.dev
```

and prod env:

```
ENV_NAME=production
APP_NAME=MyApp
API_URL=https://api-v2.app.com/
APP_SCHEME=myapp
BUNDLE_ID=com.myapp
```

The env file is loaded atop my app.config.ts through

```
import { config } from "dotenv";

config({ path: process.env.ENVFILE });
```

The env files are appropriately picked up upon running eas build --profile development/production. I can confirm that because in my app.config.ts i pass them to my extras:

```
 extra: {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
    environment: process.env.ENV_NAME,
```

and I have a red DEV ribbon rendered on the home screen if the extra.environment resolves to "development".

Now, i have a couple of issues, my bundleId ( `package: process.env.BUNDLE_ID` ) seems to always resolve to the development one, as well as the app name, whichever build i install, I'll get the DEVversion of the name as well as the dev icon and splash screens.
I'm running my builds through  `eas build --clear-cache --platform android --profile development --message "some message"` making sure i clear cache so I really don't understand whats happening.

To mention the slug field: its not changing as i want it to bind to a single expo project, but the general idea is to install the same app twice on my phone and compare envs.